# R for loop results in "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed", while condition works outside of loop

Tags: r, loops, na

Given a list of strings ('premade_txt'), I would like to save the strings meeting some conditions into a new list.

```
result <- list()
txt <- premade_txt[[1]]

for (i in 1:length(txt)) {
  
  # check which words only contain English characters, as a list of logical vals
  bool <- grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", txt[i], perl=T)
  
  # check if the word is of length 3, and also consists of only English chars 
  if ((nchar(txt[i])==3) & bool[i]) {
      
    # append the word to the list:
    result <- append(result, txt[i])}
}
```

Running the code outside of the loop worked smoothly; however, running it within the for loop resulted in the following error:

```
Error in if ((nchar(txt[i])==3) & bool[i]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What went wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Probably when `bool[i]` is out of range, but can't say without a reproducible example

Comment: @user438383 thanks! I tried using this instead:
`bool <- ifelse(!is.na(grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", txt[i], perl=T)),grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", txt[i], perl=T),FALSE)`, resulted in the same error. will try to supply a reproducible example

Comment: You want your length of `bool == 3` before the loop, essentially  `i in 1:length(bool)`  as your counter. As it is, across all values of length(txt), some `i` are <3 and that is not accounted for. Or something like that. Brain, such as it is, was moving faster than fingers. But, as suggested, `dput(head(txt))` and copy `structure(...)`, above as data.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the result of the `grep` command for the one test in the following line, you do not need to store all the grep-results in an entire vector *bool*. Just omit the `[i]`when accessing *bool*.

If you actually need all `grep` results at some later point in your code, initialize *bool* before the for-loop:

```
bool <- logical(length(txt))
```

and assign to `bool[i]` inside the loop.